# Not displaying correct option in drop-down menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I created a drop down list with links. It works properly except when I go back one page, then instead of the option which is 'selected' in the HTML, it shows the  option I had navigated to. I would like it to reset, so that the page I'm on is the one being displayed when the list is collapsed. How can I fix this?

```
<div id="drop">         
    <select name="year" id="year" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option value="sermons-2023.html"selected>2023</option>
        <option value="sermons-2022.html">2022</option>
        <option value="sermons-2021.html">2021</option>
        <option value="sermons-2020.html">2020</option>
        <option value="sermons-2019.html">2019</option>
        <option value="sermons-2018.html">2018</option>
        <option value="sermons-2017.html">2017</option>
        <option value="sermons-2016.html">2016</option>
        <option value="sermons-2015.html">2015</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the value with js in localstoreg and then after returning to the previous page you can see that the value is the same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).